# Vectorize this without using a loop

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am attempting to write the Tyler robust covariance estimation without a loop:

Here is my current implementation:

- x is a sample vector of size [nxb]
- cov is a covariance matrix of size [bxb]
- oldCov is a covariance matrix from the former iteration. it is also a [bxb] matrix

here is the current implementation:

```
invCov = pinv(oldCov);
for i = 1:n
    cov = cov + x(i,:).'*x(i,:)/sum(x(i,:)*invCov.*x(i,:),2);
end
```

now here is my question:

1. is it possible to vectorize this without the loop?
2. I am interested in trying to further improve the estimation robustness by using other post processing techniques. For this it is preferable that the result would not be the sum but a vector "covElements" of size [bxbxn] with each

   covElements(:,:,i) = x(i,:).'*x(i,:)/sum(x(i,:)*invCov.*x(i,:),2);

thank you.

Comment: I think you're missing a transpose in the code, before `invCov`

Comment: Actually, x(i,:) is size [1,b] and invCov is [b,b] so that code runs fine.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't see the dot after invcov—now I see what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorizing *piece-by-piece*, here's one [`bsxfunned`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) solution -

```
%// Vectorize : "sum(x(i,:)*invCov.*x(i,:),2)"
parte1 = sum((x*invCov).*x,2);

%// Vectorize : "x(i,:)/sum(x(i,:)*invCov.*x(i,:),2)"
xp1 = bsxfun(@rdivide,x,parte1);

%// Get vectorized covElements and cov
covElements_out = bsxfun(@times,permute(xp1,[3 2 1]),permute(x,[2 3 1]));
cov_out = xp1.'*x;
```